# I am trying to create circle avatar in Flutter. I have tried this but not giving me circle please check the code bellow:

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImagenesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImagenesPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Imágenes'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset('assets/images/wallpaper.png'),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0)),
              Image.network(
                  'https://previews.123rf.com/images/cc0collection/cc0collection2205/cc0collection220540918/186116605-oranges,-fruits,-citrus,-vitamins,-juicy,-food,-green,-leaf,-harvest,-fram,-wet,-water,-drops.jpg?fj=1'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://previews.123rf.com/images/cc0collection/cc0collection2205/cc0collection220540918/186116605-oranges,-fruits,-citrus,-vitamins,-juicy,-food,-green,-leaf,-harvest,-fram,-wet,-water,-drops.jpg?fj=1'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add an circle avater:

```
CircleAvatar(
radius: 20,
child: ClipOval(
    child: Image.network(
      'https://previews.123rf.com/images/cc0collection/cc0collection2205/cc0collection220540918/186116605-oranges,-fruits,-citrus,-vitamins,-juicy,-food,-green,-leaf,-harvest,-fram,-wet,-water,-drops.jpg?fj=1',
        ),
    ),
),
```